Angular subscribing best approach
I wonder what should be the best option to subscribe or to handle data across application, in my case, a user data should be subscribed inside service or should I make a subscribe call to my API every time I enter different admin components?
At the moment I chose to make a single call to retrieve the user and store the data inside an behavior subject.
auth.service.ts:
currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
currentUser$ = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

currentUserStateSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
currentUserState$ = this.currentUserStateSubject.asObservable();

isLoadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
isLoading$ = this.isLoadingSubject.asObservable();

// here I check for user state , I automatically update user across all // components
// and it will render only the first time component is loaded (excluding components 
// that have providers with this class)

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public router: Router,
  ) {
    if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.getUser().subscribe();
    } else {
      this.isLoadingSubject.next(false);
      this.currentUserStateSubject.next(false);
      this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
  }


/**
   * -=[### AUTH - GET USER DETAILS ###]=-
   * Retrieve user data
   * @return {Observable<any>}
   */
  public getUser(): Observable<any> {
    const body = { server_key: this.serverKey };
    this.isLoadingSubject.next(true);
    const loadingTimer = timer(500);
    return loadingTimer.pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        this.http.post(environment.getUser, body, this.httpOptions).pipe(
          catchError((error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
            this.isLoadingSubject.next(false);
            this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
            this.currentUserStateSubject.next(false);
            this.logoutUser();
            return of(null);
          }),
          timeout(10000),
          catchError((error: any) => {
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
              // Handle timeout error here
              console.log('Request timed out', error);
              // You can throw a custom error here if needed
            }
            return throwError(error); // Rethrow the error
          }),
          tap((user) => {
            this.isLoadingSubject.next(false);
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            this.currentUserStateSubject.next(true);
            console.log(this.currentUserSubject.value);
          })
        )
      )
    );
}

In my component I will only use this syntax:
this.currentUser$ = this.authService.currentUser$;
this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.currentUserState$;
this.isLoading$ = this.authService.isLoading$;

I need to know if my approach is good or should I subscribe every time to update data across components ? Thank you.

Actually, it depends on requirements. Generally, your approach is ok. Additionally, you can add update method in your service and trigger it when needed, then you'll get updated data in the same streams.
